# Existence of a continuous and unbounded map $f$ with $f(f(x))=x$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, $B$ be its unit ball: $\|x\|\leq 1$.

Does there exist a continuous map $f:H\to H$ such that $f(f(x))=x$ $\forall x\in H$, $f$ has no fixed points, and $f(B)$ is unbounded?

Comment: Continuous for which topology?

Comment: @MTS: clearly the answer is no for the weak* topology. If $f$ is weak* continuous then $f(B)$ must be compact, and it's an easy consequence of (some version of) the principle of uniform boundedness that every weak* compact set is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the $\ell^2$-norm topology. Isn't it true that there exists a homeomorphism
$$h :\ H\rightarrow H\setminus\{0\}$$
which is an identity when restricted to the unit sphere and outside the unit ball? Then the rest is straightforward.

Indeed, first of all consider involution   $i : H\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow H\setminus\{0\}$   given by formula

$$i(x) := -\frac x{x^2}$$

Now the desired involution   $j : H\rightarrow H$   is given by:

$$ j := h^{-1}\circ i\circ h$$

Regards,
           Wlod

Comment: The rest is straightforward?

Comment: Is my English off ((I am not a native speaker :-), or should I expand my answer?

Comment: I'm baffled as to how you would use $h$ to construct the desired function $f$.

Comment: I'll expand (edit) my answer above.

Comment: You mean $i(x) = x/\|x\|^2$? Your map still seems to fix every element of the unit sphere.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the minus sign ... yes, that seems to work.  Nice!

Comment: I thought (:-) that in a Hilbert space $\|x\|^2 = x^2$. But you are right, I should have written $\|x\|^2$, and I thought about it, except that LaTeX-wise it is so much harder!